# Matlab resample array based on second array

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have two datasets, both consisting of an `x` and `y` array, e.g.:

```
x_1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
y_1 = [8 12 20 3 4 9 10 55 3 2];

x_2 = [2 5 6 8 9];
y_2 = [4 18 3 12 1];
```

Now, I'd like to calculate a new metric `z = y_1 ./ y_2` but I want to compare elements of `y_1` by elements of `y_2` with the same `x`, value:

```
z = [12 4 9 55 3 2] ./ [4 18 3 12 1]
```

How can I then find this second array containing only the values of `y_2` with a corresponding `x_2` value that occurs in `x_1` in an efficient way?

So far, I came up with this solution but I doubt it's the most efficient possibility:

```
for i = 1:numel(x_2)
    z(i) = y_2(i) / y_1(y_1 == x_2(i));
end
```

Since looping over elements can generally be avoided in Matlab, I assume there's better ways to do this.

So basically, I want to resample the second dataset to make its `x_2` array equal to `x_1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* vectorize this using [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.ismember.html):

```matlab
[Lia,Locb] = ismember(x_1, x_2);

z = y_1(Lia) ./ y_2(nonzeros(Locb).');
```

Whether you *should* or not is another question. Avoiding loops in MATLAB is largely an obsolete strategy since MATLAB started introducing the JIT compilation engine. I have my doubts that vectorized version will be any faster than the for-loop, except *maybe* for the largest datasets, and I don't believe it is any more readable. YMMV

Comment: Thanks for your insight on using loops, didn't know about that. I think I'll stick to my solution for readability then.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to previous answer, but shorter:

```
y_1(ismember(x_1,x_2))./y_2
```

Note: I've checked this on Octave, as don't have Matlab license.

Comment: This will work as long as `ismember(x_1,x_2)` and `y_2` are the same length, that is when there are no elements in `x_2` that are not represented in `x_1` and that there are no duplicate in either. But if these conditions hold, it's a clever solution.